# Unusual numbering: combine alph, Alph, arabic

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, expansion

I would like to have an unusual numbering `aAa` going as follows:

```
 0 -> *
-------------------------
 1 -> a
 2 -> b
   ...
25 -> y
26 -> z
-------------------------
27 -> A
28 -> B
   ...
51 -> Y
52 -> Z
-------------------------
53 -> 1
54 -> 2
55 -> 3
   ...
```

Since it might be used in page numbering or similar sensitive contexts, the command `\@aAa` should be introduced so that `\pagenumbering{aAa}` works (I'm not going to use it this way but I still need it). As well, a fully expandable solution is welcomed.

Comment: **Remark:** I have an answer myself, but it is quite heavy and definitely not expandable. I'm searching for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the use of the already defined macros that return the alphabetical expression of a counter, this seems pretty straightforward.

### Why `\aAa` and `\@aAa`?

Firstly, what is the difference between `\<number style>` and `\@<number style>`?

Whereas the argument of `\@<number style>` is a “number” which can be a counter, a `\numexpr` or just `42` , the argument of `\<number style>` has to be the name of a LaTeX counter, to be more precise, a name of a counter defined by `\newcounter{<name>}` (which defines a TeX counter named `\c@<name>`).

It must not be a `<number>` unless, of course, someone defined a counter named `\c@<number>`, but then we could get the `<number style>` expression of `\c@<number>` but not of `<number>`!

### `\aAa`

The usual definition of `\<number style>` is:

```
\def\<number style>#1{\expandafter\@<number style>\csname c@#1\endcsname
```

I have defined `\aAa` in the same way, which brings us to `\@aAa`.

### `\@aAa`

The pretty straightforward part is that I have used a few simple if-conditions, in pseudo code:

```
if counter = 0 then
  *
else if counter < 27
  alph(counter - 26)
else if counter < 53
  Alph(counter - 52)
else
  counter - 52
end if
```

where `alph(arg)`/`Alph(arg)` returns `a`/`A` for `arg = 1`, `b`/`B` for `arg = 2`, and so on.

Which “function” (read: macro) in LaTeX does this? The `\@<number style>` ones do. `\<number style>{<arg>}` would return the value of a counter named `\c@<arg>` (which probably doesn’t even exist).

(The macro `\pagenumbering{<arg>}` redefines `\thepage` as `\@<arg>\c@page`.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\aAa#1{\expandafter\@aAa\csname c@#1\endcsname}% LaTeX
\def\@aAa#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0*%
  \else\ifnum#1<27
      \@alph{#1}%
    \else\ifnum#1<53
        \@Alph{\numexpr#1-26\relax}%
      \else
        \@arabic{\numexpr#1-52\relax}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgffor}% for the \foreach loop
\pagenumbering{aAa}
\newcounter{aAatest}
\renewcommand*{\theaAatest}{\aAa{aAatest}}
%\renewcommand*{\theaAatest}{{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\aAa{aAatest}}}}% test for spurious spaces
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for correct \meaning output
\begin{document}
0: \theaAatest\par\setcounter{aAatest}{3}
3: \theaAatest\par\setcounter{aAatest}{51}
51: \theaAatest\par\setcounter{aAatest}{55}
55: \theaAatest
\medskip

\edef\x{\theaAatest}% expansion?
\meaning\x% gives:
\show\x% gives:
% > \x=macro:
% ->3.
% l.33 \show\x
\medskip

\foreach \i in {0,...,59}{
  \setcounter{aAatest}{\i} \i: \theaAatest\par
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You have some spurious spaces in there... It is expandable: try `\edef\x{\theaAatest}\show\x`

Comment: +1 I had something similar, but I was just using `\alph`, `\Alph` (with no `@`); could you say why you used `\@alph`?

Comment: @cmhughes Quite simple: `\@alph` return the alphabetical expression of its argument (counter, `numexpr`, or a number), not the alphabetical expression of a LaTeX counter. See my updated answer for a hopefully more helpful explanation.

Comment: @cmhughes the point is that to define `\@aAa` you have to use `\@alph` and friends. To define `\aAa` directly you could use `\alph` and friends, but why to copy the code twice while the provided definition is the correctly desinged one, you see ...

Comment: (edited by moderator from non-answer) When I compile this example I get "\x=macro: ->3. l.33 \show\x % gives: ? x" and no pages of output.

Comment: @6rt4uu That is a property of the command `\show`: It shows the value of `\x` and interrupts the compilation process. To continue, simply press <enter>. Anyways, you only need the first 20 lines of the code, the rest is only a test that it works correctly.